# С чего начать изучение технологии REST?

Tags: rest, soap

Если кто работал с данной технологией или SOAP, подскажите, какой должен быть план действий при изучении данной технологии, что я должен знать и понимать до ее изучения? Если кто напишет план и ссылки на материал, который изучал - буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Пара статей: http://art-in-stamps.ru/development/restful-web-services.shtml и 
http://art-in-stamps.ru/development/richardson-maturity-model.shtml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По сути, REST - это способ передачи данных, когда с одной стороны есть HTTP сервер, и с другой - некий клиент (например - браузер), который поддерживает HTTP протокол.

Самый простой пример взаимодействия - когда ты вводишь в строке браузера адрес вроде `http://localhost/dogs/12345` и получаешь набор данных в формате JSON или XML.

Твой план:

1. [Познакомится с HTTP протоколом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP)
2. [Основные типы (методы) запросов: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B)
3. [Коды состояния HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP) - число, которое возвращает HTTP сервер с каждым запросом.
4. [Crafting Interfaces that Developers Love](https://pages.apigee.com/rs/apigee/images/api-design-ebook-2012-03.pdf) - небольшая брошюра, которая описывает, как правильно проектировать REST API сервисы.
5. [Список открытых REST API сервисов в интернете.](https://github.com/toddmotto/public-apis) - попрактиковаться в запросах.

Кроме того, для практики запросов тебе понадобиться REST API клиент, их много разных, можешь поискать в виде плагина для твоего браузера, например Postman для Chrome или REST Client для Firefox.

Если захочешь написать свой собственный REST API сервис, можешь начать с [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) или [Python Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)